# print string with variables without add new line

Tags: python-3.x

In python3 I want print a string with a couple of variables in one line only. Here the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, socket, getpass
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

def sshHost(hostname):
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()
    hostIp = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    sshSession = ConnectHandler(device_type='juniper', ip=hostIp, username=username, password=password)
    versionHostname = sshSession.send_command("show version | match Hostname:")
    print('ssh session established with {}: {}'.format(versionHostname, hostIp), end="")
    return sshSession

sshHost(sys.argv[1])
```

When function print the output is on 3 different lines:

```
ssh session established with 
Hostname: srx00.sw11.lab
: 192.168.1.1
```

I have tried to add `end` at the end of the print statement but seems not working (probably because I am note use end properly)

Comment: Do `versionHostname` and `hostIP` have newlines attached to them? try `versionHostName.strip()`?

Comment: Yes, strip() is working. Thanks :)